# Algorithms for processing visit logs

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, logging, analytics

Suppose I have a MySQL table that looks like the following, where I keep track of when (Date) a user (User.id) read an article on my website (Article.id):

```
------------------------------------------
Article_Impressions
------------------------------------------
date                | user_id | article_id
--------------------+---------+-----------
2013-04-02 15:33:23 | 815     | 2342
2013-04-02 15:38:21 | 815     | 108
2013-04-02 15:39:33 | 161     | 4815
...
```

I'm trying to determine how many session I had, as well as average session duration per user on a given day. A session ends when an article was not read within 30 minutes after another article.

**Question**

How can I efficiently determine how many session I had on a given day? I'm using PHP and MySQL.

My first idea is to query all that data for a given day, sorted by user. Then I iterate through each user, check if an impression was within 30 minutes of the last impression, and tally up a total count of session each user had that day.

Since we have around 2 million impressions a day on our site, I'm trying to optimize this report generator.

Comment: learn to use GROUP BY and MySQL Aggregation functions... that would be a starting point - don't try doing all the work in PHP

Comment: I agree with Mark Baker, I would do as much as you can in SQL, possibly using a view. You should at least be able to get the total count of sessions, but probably also average time per user.

Comment: I know MySQL pretty well. I'm definitely planning on using MySQL to sort and order the data, but can't think of any ways it could do much else. How can you group data by buckets of 30 minutes using pure SQL? Can't be done...

Comment: Convert date/time to unix timestamp, divide by 30 minutes, and cast to integer, then group by... will give you 30 minute buckets

Comment: But a session is relative to the previous visit, so I'd need to look at when the previous visit was in order to determine of 30 minutes have gone by since. If the user visits a page once every 29 minutes 100 times, this would count as a very long, but single session. The division/casting wouldn't take that into account...

Comment: If your starting premise is that it can't be done, then you won't ever do it... I've just told you how to do one thing that you said wasn't possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  @sessionId:=if(@prevUser=user_id AND diff <= 1800 , @sessionId, @sessionId+1) as sessionId,
  @prevUser:=user_id AS user_id, 
  article_id,
  date,
  diff
from 
  (select @sessionId:=0, @prevUser:=0) b
join
  (select 
    TIME_TO_SEC(if(@prevU=user_id, TIMEDIFF(date, @prevD), '00:00')) as diff,
    @prevU:=user_id as user_id,
    @prevD:=date as date,
    article_id
  from 
    tbl 
  join
    (select @prev:=0, @prevU=0)a
  order by 
    user_id, 
    date) a
```

**[Results]**:

```
| SESSIONID | USER_ID | ARTICLE_ID |                DATE | DIFF |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |     161 |       4815 | 2013-04-02 15:39:33 |    0 |
|         2 |     815 |       2342 | 2013-04-02 15:33:23 |    0 |
|         2 |     815 |        108 | 2013-04-02 15:38:21 |  298 |
|         3 |     815 |        108 | 2013-04-02 16:38:21 | 3600 |
```

This query will return a unique session for every new user and also for same user if the next article read is after 30 mins as per your requirement mentioned in your question. The diff column returns the seconds difference between the 2 articles by the same user which helps us count the sessionId. Now using this result it will be easy for you to count the average time per user and also total time per session.

Hope this helps you...

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dcae/17/0)**

Answer (score 1):

If the concept of the user "session" is important to your analytics, then I would start logging data in your table to make querying of session-related data not such a painful process.  A simple approach would be to log your PHP session ID.  If your PHP session id is set to have the same 30 minute expiry, and you log the PHP session ID to this table then you would basically have exactly what you are looking for.

Of course that won't help you with your existing records.  I would probably go ahead and create the session field and then back-populate it with randomly generated "session" id's.  I wouldn't look for a fully SQL solution for this, as it may not do what you want in terms of handling edge cases (sessions spanning across days, etc.). I would write a script to perform this backfill, which would contain all the logic you need.

My general approach would be to SELECT all the records like this:

```
SELECT user_id, date /* plus any other fields like unique id that you would need for insert */
FROM Article_Impressions
WHERE session_id IS NULL
ORDER BY user_id ASC, date ASC
```

Note: make sure you have index on both user_id and date fields.

I would then loop through the result set, building a temp array of each user_id, and loop through that array for all date values assigning a randomly generated session id which would change each time the date change was greater than 30 minutes. Once the user value increments, I would make inserts for that previous user to update the session_id values and then reset the temp array to empty and continue that process with the next user.

Note that it is probably important to take the approach of keeping a relatively small temp/working array like this, as with the number of records you are talking about, you are likely not going to be able to read the entire result set into an array in memory.

Once your data is populated, the query becomes trivial:

Unique sessions for each day:

```
SELECT DATE(date) as `day`, COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS `unique_sessions`
FROM Article_Impressions
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` DESC /* or ASC depending on how you want to view it */
```

Average sessions per day:

```
SELECT AVG(sessions_per_day.`unique_sessions`) AS `average_sessions_per_day`
FROM
  (
    SELECT DATE(date) as `day`, COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS `unique_sessions`
    FROM Article_Impressions
    GROUP BY `day`
  ) AS sessions_per_day
GROUP BY sessions_per_day.`day`
```

Note: you need an index on the new session_id field.

Comment: Keeping the session ID with the rest of the data sounds like a great idea. Thanks.